# 'add to index' takes so long. How can I skip some folder?

Tags: git

Even if i add the folder in .gitignore file,  git is trying indexing the folder. how can I skip this? Whenever I command git add index, it takes so long.

Comment: I've never seen `git add` take an unreasonable amount of time. Could you give us more details, such as what kinds of things are in the folder you're adding, how many items are in it, and exactly what command is taking so long?

Comment: You need to include system details.  Are you mounted over NFS or something?  Do you have core.preloadIndex enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git would be indexing the folder if that folder has elements already versioned.

If you want the `.gitignore` to work, you need first to make sure there is no versioned elements already recorded:

```
git rm --cached -r folder/
```

*Then* the `.gitignore` would work.